# unable to install redis 2.7+ on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: redis, ubuntu-12.04

I am new to `redis`. and I just followed `cli` to install redis `sudo apt-get install redis`.
 but the install server version is `2.2.12` . If I want to update this version and I want to install `redis 2.7 +` then how can I do this thing, please help. I am working on `ubuntu 12.04`

Comment: Belongs on [AskUbuntu.SE](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: I came here (via Google) hoping to find the command to install redis and it's actually `sudo apt-get install redis-server`

Comment: I have installed redis using `sudo apt-get install redis-server
` but I am receiving this error: `ImportError: No module named redis
`

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/88265/30354

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu repositories have the 2.2 version of Redis as you discovered. If you want the latest version, you will have to download the sources from github and install it manually.

See "Installing Redis" section in the readme over here -  https://github.com/antirez/redis

Answer (score 12):

You can install a Personal Package Archive to get the latest version. <del>A popular one seems to be https://launchpad.net/~rwky/+archive/redis</del>

edit: The one above is no longer maintained. Try https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/ubuntu/redis-server instead.

```
sudo apt-get -y install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:chris-lea/redis-server
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install redis-server
```

These commands installed the latest version for me at the time of writing.

Answer (score 0):

Try either
  sudo apt-get install redis-server
or
  http://laymansite.com/install-redis-in-ubuntu-12-04/